# How to find individual cluster SSE using simpleKmeans class methods

Tags: cluster-analysis

I am working on weka-api of class clustering. I want to implement bisecting kmeans using a wrapper around simplekmeans. Problem i am facing is ,I want to calculate individual cluster's sum of squared error(SSE) but each time when i  use getSquaredError() function it returns total SSE of all the clusters. I want to view individual cluster's SSE so that cluster with highest SSE value is bisected next. Is there any function for that or what coding technique to use for this.
Can anyone help on this. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the source.

Modify the function `getSquaredError()` to return an array of squared errors, instead of the *sum*.

Comment: Can u pls help me out...n give me a small example..
getSquaredError() is an inbuilt function..how we can modify it..if we can ..can u pls help me kut

Comment: Get the *source*. Weka is open source, you can modify it.

Comment: I know i m troubling u again n again but if u can please copy paste the source code of getsquarederror() function or send me the link...i can only view the class ,its method prototype but not the definition of method...thanks:)

Comment: Let me Google this for you: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-dev/3.7.12/weka/clusterers/SimpleKMeans.java#SimpleKMeans.getSquaredError%28%29 **But that won't help you much.** You want to get the full Weka source code, so you can also *compile* and not just *view* it.

Comment: That means i hv to override this method!

Comment: Overriding won't do. You want to add a new method `double[] getSquaredErrors()` which is trivial if you **get the source code**... you could then even submit thus to Weka for future inclusion.

Comment: (Performance-wise, you may want to look at ELKI instead of Weka, because it's tons faster: http://quipu-strands.blogspot.de/2015/12/clustering-elki-over-weka.html )

Comment: Can i ask u for something...:)

Comment: I hv to implement bisecting kmeans using a wrapper around simplekmeans..can u do this for me ..pls pls ..

Comment: No. I won't do your homework. There are sites where you can hire someone for money, of course. Your professor will be disappointed, of course.

Comment: Its ok..i m not doing copy paste stuff here...i m into this assgn for last 10 days...n now i m disheartened..anyways thanks for your help ...will trouble u again in stuck...i hope u wont mind that..  :)

Comment: No, you are failing the basic "get started coding" test... you are wasting your time *not* working and instead using Google to try to find somebody to do it for you... I won't be doing you a favor if I solved this trivial task for you.